# Find homomorphism from $f: F^{n} \to F^{m}$ such that the set of solutions is $= ker(f)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory, linear-transformations, systems-of-equations

Let $F$ be a field. Given an $(m \times n)-$matrix
$$ M = (t_{ij})_{1 \leq i \leq m,\, 1 \leq j \leq n}$$

over $F$, define $rank(M)$ as the dimension of the subspace $Col(M)$ of $F^{m}$ spanned by all columns $(t_{ip})_{1 \leq i \leq m,\, p=1,2,\cdots , n}$.

Consider the set $S \subseteq F^{n}$ of all solutions $\{x_{1},x_{2},\cdots , x_{n}\}$ of the homogeneous linear system of equations over $F$:

$$(15.3) \begin{cases} t_{11}x_{1}+t_{12}x_{2}+\cdots + t_{1n}x_{n}=0, \\
t_{21}x_{1}+t_{22}x_{2}+\cdots + t_{2n}x_{n} = 0, \\ \vdots \\ t_{m1}x_{1}+t_{m2}x_{2} + \cdots + t_{mn}x_{n} = 0 \end{cases} $$

I need to find a homomorphism $f: F^{n} \to F^{m}$ such that $S = \ker(f)$.

I now that usually, for $M \in M_{mn}$, the map $T:x \mapsto Mx$ does the job of having the solution set equal to the kernel. Does that work here? It's a linear transformation and not a "homomorphism" per se, but I've found that they work pretty much the same way.

Aside from this, assuming what I've said here is correct, is there any kind of formal proving process I need to go through, and if so, could you give me any pointers to that effect?

Also, knowing $rank(M)$, I need to compute the dimension of $S$. Normally, I would use the rank + nullity theorem, but here, I am dealing with both matrices and linear transformations and I have never seen a form of the rank + nullity theorem that mixed them both. If someone could point me in the right direction as to how to do this part as well, I would be extremely grateful.

Thanks ahead of time for your patience!

Comment: $F$-linear maps are the morphisms in the category of $F$-vector spaces. There's nothing to prove.

Comment: @Bernard Is that the correct map that I mentioned?

Comment: It is, You only have to associtae a linear mmap to the matrix. This simply means choosing a basis, e.g. the canonical basis.

Comment: @Bernard thank you. I have edited the question to ask something additional.

Comment: @Bernard I know this is an old post, but you could you please explain how to do that?

Comment: @VinnyChase: How to do *what* ?

Comment: @Bernard Sorry should have been more specific.  Associate a linear mmap to the matrix as you mentioned in your last comment

Comment: @VinnyChase: Well, you simply  multiply  a column-vector with $n$ rows by the $m\times n$ matrix on the left.

Comment: @Bernard so exactly the map the OP mentioned?

Comment: @VinnyChase: Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *rank* of a linear map $T$ from a finite dimensional vector space $V$ to the   finite dimensional vector space $W$ (possibly the same) is the dimension of its image $T(V)$.

If we choose bases in $V$ and $W$, and represent the linear map $T$ with its matrix $M_T$ relative to these bases, the rank of $T$ is the number of linearly independent columns of $M_T$,  and also the number of linearly independent rows of $M_T$, in other words the rank of $T$ is the rank of its matrix $M_T$.

Similarly the set $S$ of solutions of a matrix equation $MX=0$ corresponds to coordinates of the vectors $u$ in the vector space $V$ such that $T(u)=0$ in $W$, so the *nullity* of $M_T$  is just the dimension of $\ker T$, and the *rank-nullity* theorem:
$$\operatorname{rank}(M_T)+ \operatorname{nullity}(M_T)=n$$
corresponds to  the  *rank theorem*:
$$\dim(\operatorname{Im}T)+\dim(\ker T)=\dim V.$$

Answer (score 0):

Find a basis $s_1,...,s_k$ for $S$ and define $f(s_j)=0 ;  1\leq j \leq k$ , then extend into a basis $s_1,s_2,...s_n$for $F^n$ and use the fact that the nullspace is orthogonal to the row space to make sure the kernel is precisely given by $S$.