# Find a homomorphism $f:F^n \rightarrow F^m$ such that such that the solution set is the kernel of $f$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to understand this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2376983/find-homomorphism-from-f-fn-to-fm-such-that-the-set-of-solutions-is), but I'm getting lost figuring out how the map is a homomorphism.  Could someone please explain it to me?  The original question was:

> Let $F$ be a field. Given an $(m \times n)-$matrix
>   $$ M = (t_{ij})_{1 \leq i \leq m,\, 1 \leq j \leq n}$$
>
> over $F$, define $rank(M)$ as the dimension of the subspace $Col(M)$ of $F^{m}$ spanned by all columns $(t_{ip})_{1 \leq i \leq m,\, p=1,2,\cdots , n}$.
>
> Consider the set $S \subseteq F^{n}$ of all solutions $\{x_{1},x_{2},\cdots , x_{n}\}$ of the homogeneous linear system of equations over $F$:
>
> $$(15.3) \begin{cases} t_{11}x_{1}+t_{12}x_{2}+\cdots + t_{1n}x_{n}=0, \\
> t_{21}x_{1}+t_{22}x_{2}+\cdots + t_{2n}x_{n} = 0, \\ \vdots \\ t_{m1}x_{1}+t_{m2}x_{2} + \cdots + t_{mn}x_{n} = 0 \end{cases} $$
>
> I need to find a homomorphism $f: F^{n} \to F^{m}$ such that $S = \ker(f)$.
>
> I now that usually, for $M \in M_{mn}$, the map $T:x \mapsto Mx$ does the job of having the solution set equal to the kernel. Does that work here? It's a linear transformation and not a "homomorphism" per se, but I've found that they work pretty much the same way.
>
> Aside from this, assuming what I've said here is correct, is there any kind of formal proving process I need to go through, and if so, could you give me any pointers to that effect?

I understand why the solution set is the kernel, but I'm not able to show its a homomorphism.  Is it because you can consider the inverse map $T^{-1}: y = Mx \rightarrow M^{-1}y$, which makes T a bijection and then you can consider elements $x,y$ and then $T(x+y) = M(x+y) = Mx + My = T(x) + T(y)$.

The comment in the previous post that is confusing me the most is "You only have to associtae a linear mmap to the matrix. This simply means choosing a basis, e.g. the canonical basis."  Could someone please explain what this means/how to do it?

Comment: I believe the common usage is that a "homomorphism" of vector spaces is literally the same thing as a linear transformation. You seem to be thinking of an "isomorphism", i.e. an invertible linear transformation.

Comment: @JustinYoung so because T is a linear transformation it is a homomorphism so I'm done?

Comment: Yes, the problem seems to be a formality with the goal of solidifying the definitions.